# How can I use a for loop to create an array and assign linear values?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I want to create an array and using a for loop and I want to assign values with an increment of 1o. So far here is what I have and I am not getting the result I want...

```
public class ArrayDemo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int array[] = new int[10];
        System.out.println("The array elements are: ");

        for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) { // Controls index...
            for (int j = 0; j < 101; j += 10) { // Controls value of each array index...
                array[i] = j;
                System.out.println(array[i]);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my output [Stack overflow won't let me have the whole output so here is the shortened version; This output (starting at /* and ending at */) was repeated 10 full times. It printed from 0 to 100 ten times with an increment of 10]:

```
The array elements are:
   /*
    0
    10
    20
    30
    40
    50
    60
    70
    80
    90
    100
    */
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is what I want. For every index, I want one value and the next value should be an increment of 1o:

```
The array elements are:
    0
    10
    20
    30
    40
    50
    60
    70
    80
    90
```

Comment: @user actually `j < 100` would be right, but they have `j < 101`, so...

Comment: you don't even need the 2nd loop,.  just assign i*10 to the elements, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop - the value is always the index multiplied by 10:

```java
for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
     array[i] = i * 10;
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you don't have to use loops, this could arguably be done more elegantly with a stream:

```
int[] array = IntStream.range(0, 10).map(i -> i * 10).toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a nested for loop to assign values into a single array.

Populate each index by `i*10` rather than introduce `j`.

You should also print the array in a new loop, otherwise, there's not much purpose for keeping the array and printing it in the same location

And rather than `<= array.length - 1`, you'll want `< array.length`

You can also use an `IntStream`, which is the modern way to achieve the same result

Comment: how would it look if I use IntRange like you said?